# Keyword not supported MultipleActiveResultSets

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-mars

We are using a custom Membership Provider in an ASP.NET MVC application. We have been experiencing intermittent 'System.InvalidOperationException - There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.' problems with the class so I decided to enabled MARS.

This is the connection string in the web config...

```
<add name="CustomMembershipServices" connectionString="User ID=CUSTOM_USER;Password=pwd;Database=OUR_DB;Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Our code now throws an ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'multipleactiverecordsets' at the following line..

```
protected void CreateAndOpenConnection()
{
    // Exception thrown here...
    _connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
    _connection.Open();
}
```

The same exception is seen when targeting SQL2005 Express and SQL2008 Standard editions. Any suggestions?

In response to AdaTheDev here is the method that uses the data reader...

```
public bool CheckUserPassword(long userID, string password)
{
    bool success = false;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
    {
        try
        {
            CreateAndOpenConnection();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = CreateSqlCommandForStoredProcedure("CheckPassword"))
            {
                IPasswordUtility generator = new PasswordUtility();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserID", userID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", generator.HashPassword(password));

                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    success = reader.HasRows;

                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseConnection();
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

I cannot see any reason why this would be creating multiple data readers on the same connection.

Comment: Hmm, have updated my answer. Can't see anything wrong in that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the ASP.NET Provider framework treating my class as a static singleton ...

["Question: When is a non-static class static?"](http://goodcoffeegoodcode.blogspot.com/2010/02/question-when-is-non-static-class.html)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you actually need MARS for a functional reason, my recommendation would be to focus on the underlying issue - it sounds like (and I could be wrong!) the expected/intended behaviour of the class is to not open multiple datareaders against a single connection at the same time.

If that is the case, then you should make sure datareaders are closed properly before another is opened on the same connection - it sounds like there is a situation where this is not being done. Using MARS as a workaround would still leave the fact that there is something not being closed properly.

**Edit 1:**
That code does look OK to me in terms of clearing up the datareaders etc. Unless there's some multi-threading going on, causing a problem through the use of the shared _connection object? (I'm doubting this is the case). Are there any other methods in the class that aren't closing a datareader?